# Any one of you should use plural verb or singular verb?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Anyone one of you has or have? Anyone should be using has, but you should be using have. What about anyone of you?

Comment: 'anyone' and 'any' one of you are totally different things.

Comment: It is short for '_Does_ any one of you have...?'